# Difference between C and C$ Share Name on Windows 7

Tags: windows

This is probably a very basic question, but i do not know the answer.
When I click on Start Menu and then Computer Management. Click on Shared Folders and then on Shares, I see Sharename= "C$" with Folder path "C:\" And 
Sharename= "C" with Folder path "C:\".

I do not know the difference between C and C$. Can anybody guide me
Thanks
MR

Comment: C$ is a share created by Windows, C must be a share that you (or perhaps some third-party software) created.

Comment: one more question: if i shared C=C:\ then I can access through \\IP\C to access it, but why i cannot access the \\IP\C$. thanks in advance if any one can give some comments.

Answer (score 0):

Share names with a `$` suffix are hidden shares, they are not displayed in the Network part of the shell namespace in Explorer but you can access them if you know the name.

The admin$ share and all drive volume shares are [administrative shares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_share) created by Windows. You can [disable them](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/954422/how-to-remove-administrative-shares-in-windows-server-2008) if you want to.